# How can I find the shortest way to an item in an loping carousel with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a Looping Carousel with 5 slides. How do I determine with javascript which way (forward or backward) requires less steps to get from a current slide to a new slide?

ie Currently on Slide 3, and would like to go to Slide 0. In this case going forward would be less steps than going back.

(0), 1, 2, [3], 4, (0), 1, 2, etc..

Ive come up with this, but seems hacky. Am I missing a concept?

```
const targetSlide = 0;
const currentSlide = 3;
const itemCount = 5;
let forwardRange;
let backwardsRange;
if(currentSlide != targetSlide){
  for(let i = 0; i < itemCount; i++){
    let j = currentSlide + i;
    if(j >= itemCount){ 
      j = j - itemCount;
    }
    if(j == targetSlide){
      forwardRange = i;
      backwardsRange = itemCount - i;
    }
  }
  if(forwardRange - backwardsRange <= 0){
    console.log('go forward')
  }else{
    console.log('go backward')
  }
}
```

Comment: Just compare `Math.abs(currentSlide - targetSlide) <=> itemCount/2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the cost of going either forwards or backwards and use that to determine the direction.

```
const targetSlide = 0;
const currentSlide = 3;
const itemCount = 5;

const forwardsCost = currentSlide < targetSlide
  ? targetSlide - currentSlide
  : itemCount - currentSlide + targetSlide;

const backwardsCost = currentSlide > targetSlide
  ? currentSlide - targetSlide
  : currentSlide + itemCount - targetSlide;
```